# filter, sort and limit an unmodifiable list in Java

Tags: java, sorting, filter, limit, guava

I want to filter, then sort and then limit an unmodifiable list in Java and Guava. Is there any smart way to do this more efficient than below?

```
public static <T> List<T> execute(final List<T> list, final Predicate<? super T> filter, final Comparator<? super T> sort, final Integer limit) {
    final List<T> newList = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(list, filter));
    Collections.sort(newList, sort);

    if (limit > newList.size()) {
        return newList;
    }
    return newList.subList(0, limit);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Yes... there's Java 8 ! Are you using it or no ?

Comment: No, I wish I was, but I am using JDK v5. But please feel free to answer the question for JDK v8 for sake of completeness!

Comment: What are Lists and Iterables classes ?

Comment: These are from Guava. I will edit my question to include that.

Comment: I would frankly tend to inline this into your callers rather than trying to do all this in one method.

Comment: @LouisWasserman This is a utility function, which prepares the list in advance. The result list is accessed a lot of times, so it makes sense to do it only once. You can compare it with a WHERE/ORDER BY/LIMIT SQL statement on a raw list.

Comment: @TweemaalZeven: So what?  I'm not suggesting inlining this into every place the list is accessed; I'm suggesting inlining this into the place the list is created.  Passing in predicates that might or might not be null seems silly: instead, inline this method at the point where you know what the predicate is.

Comment: @LouisWasserman The input list is created/retrieved in several places. In my opinion, it makes sense to create one single utility function. That said, I can see your point. However, that's not really my question :). I am wondering if there are smart ways to combine filtering, sorting en limiting in single steps.

Comment: Won't make anything more efficient, but you can use `Predicate<? super T>` and `Comparator<? super T>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (limit != null) {
    return newList.subList(0, limit);
}
```

This will blow whenever `limit > newList.size()`.

I guess, only one thing can be optimized: You don't really have to sort the whole collection, if you want only a part of it. Doing this is [a bit complicated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting), so you should measure first if you really need it.

---

As stated in the comments, it's actually easy, as Guava already does it:

```
public static <T> List<T> execute(
        final List<T> list,
        final Predicate<? super T> filter,
        final Comparator<? super T> sort,
        final Integer limit) {
    final FluentIterable<T> filtered = FluentIterable.from(list).filter(filter);
    return Ordering.from(sort).leastOf(filtered, limit);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, partial interesting is interesting!

Comment: @TweemaalZeven Did you mean partial interesting is sorting? ;)

Comment: @TweemaalZeven @maaartinus Actually, Guava can do partial sorting for you with [Ordering.leastOf](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#leastOf(java.lang.Iterable,%20int)) and `greatestOf`.

Comment: That's nice! Does this makes sense? `Ordering.from(sort).leastOf(FluentIterable.from(list).filter(filter), limit);`

Comment: @TweemaalZeven: Yeah, that makes sense though it might read a little better to do the filtering and the `leastOf` as separate steps.

Comment: @TweemaalZeven Yes. I updated my answer. I also split the line as Colin suggested. But you shouldn't update your question the way you did (removed the original). Preserving the original and possibly adding the chosen solution is the way to go.

Comment: OK, I accepted this as the answer. @maaartinus I would rather to have the discussions about the null checks, utility functions, ... be removed. Even though they are very much appreciated, it wasn't really my question. I was too quick to copy/paste dummy code.

Comment: @TweemaalZeven Thanks for accepting! The discussion will stay and there's nothing we could do about it. It's also not really important, what matters are the questions and the answers, not the comments. Consider the whole content of SO including your question as belonging to the community. You've got your answer and now imagine someone coming here with a similar problem. Now, Dici's answer makes no sense. But this isn't bad as we have the history, too. So everything's fine, just think twice before editing a question.

Comment: Noted, thanks for your patience. I am fairly new in Java and SO (a few months). I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<T> newList = FluentIterable.from(list)
    .filter(predicate)
    .limit(limit)
    .toSortedList(comparator);
// (This sorts last so is behaviorally different from the original example, but it
//  gives an idea of a somewhat more readable approach to this type of thing.)

// Java 8's Stream, unlike Guava's FluentIterable, has a sort method which
// makes this easier:
List<T> newList = list.stream()
    .filter(predicate)
    .sort(comparator)
    .limit(limit)
    .collect(toList());
```

Just use that *instead of* your `execute` method, and just don't call `filter` if you don't have a predicate to filter with, etc. Note how it's clear what's being done when you look at that code. Compare it to:

```
List<T> newList = execute(list, predicate, comparator, limit);
```

or even worse:

```
List<T> newList = execute(list, null, comparator, null);
```

Defining a single method like this only obfuscates your code.

Comment: I believe this is incorrect. You should first filter, then sort and then limit. Here, sorting is done before limiting.

Comment: @TweemaalZeven: Ok, so unfortunately you'd have to change it up a bit. The point stands that doing these steps explicitly is preferable.

Comment: Say I have to filter, sort, ... a list at several places in my code. One time I only have to filter, another time I have to filter and sort, ... Do you propose to check for null inline, over and over again, instead of using a utility function?

Comment: @Tweemaal Zeven : I believe this is a nice solution, this syntax is similar to Java 8 streams. If you want more flexibility, combine it with my advice of overloading the method (for example `execute(list,comparator,limit)` would just return `execute(list,Predicates.alwaysTrue(),comparator,limit)`

Comment: OK, makes sense. I'll alter my question in the assumption that all variables are given. I would like to focus on my question: is there a smart way to filter and/of sort and/or limit. The partitial sort was interesting.

Comment: Er... so these places in your code you _have_ a `Predicate` that might be `null`? I assumed you were using your `execute` method by explicitly passing in `null` when you didn't want to do one of the operations. If that's not the case, well... you could make methods like `filterIfNotNull(List, Predicate)` I guess. I'd try to avoid that situation in the first place though.

Comment: :( It's hard to comment on this without providing much more code, which isn't desirable. Please, let's not nitpick and focus on the question.

Comment: @TweemaalZeven: I'd strongly advise that you reconsider whatever design led you to that point -- this is a pretty bad design smell.

Comment: @TweemaalZeven: My main point is just that throwing unrelated things (`Predicate`, `Comparator`, `Integer`) into a method and getting a `List` out makes it very unclear what's actually happening. How does the calling code know (without digging into your `execute` method's code) whether the limiting is happening before or after the sorting? It's really not obvious what the method is doing at all, much less that detail. Anyway, that's my advice.

Answer (score 2):

Your tests quite complicate the thing... If you want the user to be able to call this method without using a filter (for example), just overload your method. `null` should not be a legal value to that kind of parameters.

Comment: It's a utility function, not a class method.

Comment: This answer still works with utility functions. You can overload your function with, for example, `execute(final List<T> list, final Predicate<T> filter)` or `execute(final List<T> list, final Comparator<T> sort)` or `execute(final List<T> list, final Predicate<T> filter, final Comparator<T> sort)`